# On click to menu-toggle change the Menu to Log In

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nav menu.

On click of the Menu button, I want to replace it with Login text

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class = "container">
    <!--Collapse menu with three lines-->
    <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
      <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
      <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <!--Actual menu-->
    <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class = "active">
          <a data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse" href = "#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse" href = "#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse" href = "#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse" href = "#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I added a class like this

```
<div id="displaylogin" style="display:none;" >

                  <a href="#" class="menu-toggle">LOG IN <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

And trying to show hide like this using the JS.

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.align-right').removeClass("visibleClass");
    $('.displaylogin').addClass("visibleClass");
});
});
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/b83hfm8t/) the fiddle for the same.

Comment: What is not working? What have you tried? Where have you searched for solutions before you came here (urls)? - also, I'd recommend writing attributes for tags without spaces, this makes for much cleaner code, e.g. `<div class="myclass-1 myclass-2">sample content</div>`

Comment: Could you add the above code to the *question* rather than put it in a *comment* it looks quite messy that way as you can see ^.^

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to bind the `click` handler to the wrong element.

From what I can see, within the `div#displaylogin` you have an `a` element with the class `menu-toggle` however since the `div#displaylogin` is hidden you'll never click on it since it's not visible or clickable within a hidden element.

If you want your code to trigger in the first place you'd have to bind it to the `button.navbar-toggle`.

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
    // this line will not work provided the example code
    // this is because this class is not in the example
    // also this classname should not be used as a selector since you'll use it alot
    // when you're using it all over the page jQuery will try to remove this class from every element with class 'align-right'
    $('.align-right').removeClass('visibleClass')
    // your element uses an ID, not a CLASS - therefore the '.' needs to be a '#'
    $('.displaylogin').addClass('visibleClass')
});
```

The above example tries to point out what is going wrong however I have some additional recommendations so that your code won't turn into frog-soup later on in development.

When you want to bind something to a single element in JS, it's best to use an ID as they are (supposed to be) unique on the page.

This prevents screw-ups when it comes to you making changes later in your code.

also, using the class `.align-right` as a selector rings like a million alarm bells on my side since this class has such general naming I am assuming that you're going to re-use it on multiple elements.

In turn, every time you re-use that class on different elements it will try to remove the `visibleClass` from **every** element that has `class="align-right"`. Can you see how that can become a problem?

This is all just advice so don't take it the wrong way, we're all trying to help each other here and that's what I'm trying to do right now :)

Fixing these issues and updating your question accordingly will allow us to help you until your problem is fixed.

It is also very important to understand that selectors are a very simple thing with very complex consequences when used improperly (as with this `.align-right` case).

I can't really say this is an answer but it's to large for a comment so I'm just going to keep updating this when more information is available.

Try to debug what you already have with my advice and come back to edit your question if you wish it to be solved, good luck in the process ;)